# Powershell Workflow Parallel Statement Shared Variables

Tags: powershell, azure, parallel-processing, workflow

I'm having some difficulty understanding why the code below is behaving the way it is.  I've done numerous searches in Google and StackOverflow and can't find anything that seems to point to a solution for this.

In an Azure Automation Runbook, I'm trying to run the same activity with different parameters in a Parallel block.  I've managed to refine the issue down to the basic building blocks and it happens in Powershell Workflow without Azure involved as well.

When I execute this code in Powershell, the output seems to get stomped on and randomness ensues.  This results in my modular workflow activities misbehaving badly.

If I run this same section of code outside of a parallel block (with or without a sequence block) it works fine.  (You can see the commented out blocks in the code below).

The other thing I noticed is that if I don't have the 3rd workflow activity involved, the parallel works fine (if it just sets the value directly instead of using the Output value from the 3rd workflow).

However, once Test calls TestChild calls TestGetLocationValue the parallel block returns the random and unexpected results.

Can someone please explain:

1. Why is the behavior happening?
2. What is a workaround / fix to allow this to work correctly?

Here is the output from a couple of runs:

**Run One**
    PS U:> Test

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Tag                            P4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Location                       {Hi, LP4, System.Collections.Hashtable}                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tag                            P5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Location                       Hi, LP5                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tag                            P6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Location                       Hi, LP6
```

**Run Two**
    PS U:> Test

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Tag                            P1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Location                       Hi, LP1
```

**Run Three**
*(With Verbose, Note the "HashTable" references)*

```
PS U:\> Test -Verbose
VERBOSE: [localhost]:Parallel Run:
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P2] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P1] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P4] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P3] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P5] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P6] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P7] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P8] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P9] Location before call: ''
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P2] Location after call: 'Hi, LP2'

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Tag                            P2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Location                       Hi, LP2                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P3] Location after call: 'Hi, LP3'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P1] Location after call: 'Hi, LP1'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P4] Location after call: 'Hi, LP4 System.Collections.Hashtable'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P6] Location after call: 'Hi, LP6 System.Collections.Hashtable'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P5] Location after call: 'Hi, LP5 System.Collections.Hashtable'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P8] Location after call: 'Hi, LP8'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P7] Location after call: 'Hi, LP7'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[P9] Location after call: 'Hi, LP9'
VERBOSE: [localhost]:[Test] Location Value After Parallel (Proves that Location doesn't leak to root workflow): ''
```

**Code Block (Test.ps1)**

```
workflow TestGetLocationValue
{
    param
    (
        $tag
    )

    $myLocation = "Hi, $tag"
    Write-Output $myLocation
}

workflow TestChild
{
    param
    (
        $tag
    )

    <#Write-Verbose "[$tag] MyLocation before call (Proves that mylocation doesn't leak to testchild workflow): '$myLocation'"#>
    Write-Verbose "[$tag] Location before call: '$location'"
    $location = TestGetLocationValue -tag "L$tag"
    <# This works: $location = "Hi, $tag" #>
    Write-Verbose "[$tag] Location after call: '$location'"
    <#Write-Verbose "[$tag] MyLocation after call Value (Proves that mylocation doesn't leak to testchild workflow): '$myLocation'"#>

    Write-Output @{
        Tag = $tag
        Location = $location
    }
}

workflow Test
{
    $location = $null

    <#
    Write-Verbose "Normal Run:"
    TestChild -tag "N1"
    TestChild -tag "N2"
    TestChild -tag "N3"
    TestChild -tag "N4"
    TestChild -tag "N5"
    TestChild -tag "N6"
    TestChild -tag "N7"
    TestChild -tag "N8"
    TestChild -tag "N9"
    Write-Verbose "[Test] Location Value After Normal (Proves that Location doesn't leak to root workflow): '$location'"
    #>

    Write-Verbose "Parallel Run:"
    Parallel
    {
        TestChild -tag "P1"
        TestChild -tag "P2"
        TestChild -tag "P3"
        TestChild -tag "P4"
        TestChild -tag "P5"
        TestChild -tag "P6"
        TestChild -tag "P7"
        TestChild -tag "P8"
        TestChild -tag "P9"
    }
    Write-Verbose "[Test] Location Value After Parallel (Proves that Location doesn't leak to root workflow): '$location'"

    <#
    Write-Verbose "Sequence Run:"
    Sequence
    {
        TestChild -tag "S1"
        TestChild -tag "S2"
        TestChild -tag "S3"
        TestChild -tag "S4"
        TestChild -tag "S5"
        TestChild -tag "S6"
        TestChild -tag "S7"
        TestChild -tag "S8"
        TestChild -tag "S9"
    }
    Write-Verbose "[Test] Location Value After Sequence (Proves that Location doesn't leak to root workflow): '$location'"
    #>
}
```

Comment: What's going on in `TestGetLocationValue`? It's possible that this function is not thread safe.

Comment: Changing TestGetLocationValue to: 
    workflow TestGetLocationValue
    {
        param
        (
            $tag
        )

        "Hi, $tag"
    } doesn't appear to help the case.

Comment: It still seems quite likely that the issue lies here somehow. The routine is basically setting a value and returning it back to the caller. (Write-Output is the method to return values as far as I understand Powershell and is marked as running locally only in the workflow documentation).